# How to create a procedure to certain probability?

Tags: probability

Here is the question,

Describe a procedure that takes as input two integers a and b such that 0 < a < b
and, using fair coin flips, produces as output heads with probability a/b and tails
with probability (b-a)/b. Give a bound on the expected number of coin flips,
which should be O(1) (Hint: Represent a/b in binary.)

I got really no idea how should I start. Hint's aren't helping cause I am not being able to understand the question , and what it wants. Please explain.

Comment: Hint: how would you do this for (a,b)=(1,4)? For (a,b)=(1,3)?

Comment: flip coin twice (a,b) = (1,4). Probability of two heads is 1/4 . Is it something like this?

Comment: O(1)? You sure? I'd expect O(b). Which, since $b$ is a parameter, really isn't the same - otherwise just about any algorithm would be O(1)...

Comment: And for (a,b)=(1,3)?

Comment: @fgp O(log(b)), actually.

Comment: @Did I'm confused - how do you get probability $\frac{1}{3^n}$ *exactly* with $c\cdot n$ flips? I can see how you can get it approximately, but doesn't the fact that the binary representation of $\frac{1}{3^n}$ isn't finite cause trouble?

Comment: @Did Forget it, I was being stupid - it says expected number of coin flips, not maximum number of coin flips. I see it now.

Comment: @fgp Yes, "bounded" vs "integrable" is exactly the point. But the silence of the OP is not a good sign, I must say...

Comment: So , what should I do?

Comment: Well, you might want to solve the case (a,b)=(1,3), to begin with--or to explain why you find it difficult. (And maybe, mayyybe, use @ in the comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a procedure that works for any $p\in(0,1)$ returning HEAD with probability $p$ using an expected number of 2 tosses.

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots\in\{0,1\}$ be the outcomes of a sequence of coin flips, scoring heads as 1 and tails as 0. Now, define
$$
Y_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{X_i}{2^i}\in[0,1],\quad
Y_\infty=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{X_i}{2^i}\in[0,1]
$$
where $Y_k$ is simply the number $0.X_1X_2\ldots X_k$ when written as a binary number. (By the way, what's the correct name for a binary "decimal" number?)

The number $Y_\infty$ will be uniform in $[0,1]$, and so the probability that $Y_\infty<p$ is exactly $p$, and so we return HEAD if $Y_\infty<p$. However, determining the exact value of $Y_\infty$ depends on an infinite number of tosses, and so is not feasible.

However, we know that
$$
Y_k\le Y_\infty\le Y_k+\frac{1}{2^k}
$$
and so may stop if either $Y_k>p$ or $Y_k+1/2^k<p$. Actually, since $Y_\infty=Y_k$ or $Y_\infty=Y_k+1/2^k$ have probability 0, we may strengthen the stopping rule to $Y_k\ge p$ or $Y_k+1/2^k\le p$.

After $k$ tosses, you know which of the $2^k$ intervals $[Y_k,Y_k+1/2^k]$ contains $Y_\infty$ (with probability 0 of $Y_\infty$ actually being on the border between two such intervals, so I'll ignore that case). The chance that the interval specified by $Y_k$ is the one containing $p$ is $1/2^k$ (although you might do a little better if $p$ lies at the border between two intervals). Thus, there's a $1/2^k$ chance that you'll need more than $k$ tosses. This makes the expected number of tosses (in the worst case scenario where $p$ is not a faction on the form $m/2^q$)
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots=2.
$$

Comment: A somewhat simpler way to visualize what's going on is to imagine flipping a coin $X_i$ as you "walk" along the binary representation $0.b_1 b_2 \ldots$ of $0 \leq \frac{a}{b} < 1$. You continue as long as $X_i = b_i$, i.e. as long as the random $0-1$ sequence your coin flips produce are a prefix of $b_1 b_2 \ldots$. Once $X_i \neq b_i$, you output HEADS if $X_i < b_i$ and TAILS if $x_i > b_i$.